# Any tricks for using the currvita style with tex4ht?

Tags: tex4ht, cv, html, xml, currvita

TeX4ht doesn't quite understand the currvita style's `cvlist` environment.  It appears that `cvlist` takes the heading as an argument, typesets this heading into an `\sbox`, and uses the `sbox` inside the first list item.  TeX4ht then typesets the first list item incorrectly.  Any quick fixes floating around?

Answer (score 2):

You did not provide a `mwe`, so I used this LaTeX code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[]{currvita}
\begin{document}
\begin{cvlist}{experiences}
\item something about it
\item this was a nightmare
\end{cvlist}
\end{document}
```

which produces PDF:

[image]

when processed with `htlatex`, `cvlist` is transformed into `dl` tag, where text "expereinces" is in tag `dt` and `\item` are transformed into `dd`. It is possible to achieve layout similar to the `pdf` version useing some `CSS` code. You can add CSS to your document through custom config file, eg, `curr.cfg`:

```
\Preamble{html} 
\begin{document} 

\Css{dl {margin: 2em 0;
    padding: 0;
}}
\Css{dt { position: relative;
    left: 0;
    float:left;
    width: 6em;
}}
\Css{dd { border-left: 1px solid \#000;
    margin: 0 0 0 8em;
    padding: 0 0 .5em .5em;
}}

\EndPreamble
```

and then you can call `htlatex yourfile "curr"`.