# htlatex puts images for math formula in the wrong place if imgdir option used

Tags: html, tex4ht

I'm creating html from LaTex using the command `htlatex ebook "html,info,imgdir:img/"` All images are in the subdirectory `img/` and this works perfectly. However I have a footnote containing a formula:

```
può calcolare come somma di una serie infinita\footnote{$\frac{\pi}{4}=1-\frac{1}
{3}+\frac{1}{5}-\frac{1}{7}+\frac{1}{9}-\cdots$}, di cui calcolare la somma di
```

htlatex creates a html file for the footnote `(ebook2.html)` linked from the main file and 6 png files `(ebook[0-5]x.png)` for the various parts of the formula.

The problem is that the png files are created in the same directory as the footnote html file, but inside it the references are to `img/ebook0x.png` for example.

What should I do to force image creation inside subdir `img/` (not good, it pollute the book image dir) or better removing img/ from created image references?

Note that the observed behavior makes sense. I asked all images to be under `img/` and in `tex4ht.env` there is the **G** line that converts from `zz*.ps` to `png`. So seems the only solution is to modify this line to put the result under `img/`

Comment: try to configure image inclusion. see http://tug.org/applications/tex4ht/mn5.html#QQ1-5-20 create custom config file, like http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/25809/2891 I cannot test it now, but hope it will work

Comment: Thanks, but no change in output. BTW in the cfg file you need to use `'` instead of `"`, otherwise I receive a lot of Undefined sequence errors.